# Left join for 3 tables with Where not working as expected

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables such as:

```
Versions         Names                        Cell
ID Version       ID   Name   Indicator        ID   Number
1   1.0          1    Joe     Y               1    1234 
2   1.1          1    Black   N               2    5678 
3   1.2          2    David   N               3    4786
4   2.0          2    Troy    N
                 2    George  Y
```

Expected Output

```
ID  Number       Version   Name   Indicator   
1   1234         1.0       Joe     Y             
2   5678         1.1       George  Y          
3   4786         1.2       NULL    NULL
```

I want to get

1. all records from the "Versions" table with "Version" starting with "1" and
2. the "Name" and "Indicator" as "Y" from the "Names" table for records from #1 and
3. "Number" from the "Cell" table from #1

I think I need a LEFT JOIN. This does not give me the expected output. Where am I going wrong?

```
   SELECT a.ID, b.Number, a.Version, c.Name, c.Indicator
   FROM Version a LEFT JOIN Cell b ON a.ID = b.ID
   LEFT JOIN Names c ON a.ID = c.ID
   WHERE a.Version LIKE '1%' AND c.Indicator = 'Y'
```

Comment: Chose table aliases that make sense, like v as in version, c as in cell, and n as in names. (Instead of a, b and c.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a condition on the "outer joined" table in the `WHERE` clause effectively turns the outer join into an inner join, because every row that is retained by the outer join will contain a `null` value in that column, but the condition `c.Indicator = 'Y'` in the where clause will remove those rows again.

To fix this, move `c.Indicator = 'Y'` into the join condition:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Number, a.Version, c.Name, c.Indicator
FROM Version a 
  LEFT JOIN Cell b ON a.ID = b.ID
  LEFT JOIN Names c ON a.ID = c.ID AND c.Indicator = 'Y'
WHERE a.Version LIKE '1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering for two reasons:

- I think the `version` condition is not correct.
- Fix the table aliases.

So, I think you really want:

```
SELECT v.ID, c.Number, v.Version, n.Name, n.Indicator
FROM Version v LEFT JOIN
     Cell c
     ON v.ID = c.ID LEFT JOIN
     Names n
     ON v.ID = n.ID AND n.Indicator = 'Y'
WHERE v.Version LIKE '1.%';
```

The reason for the `.` is so the `WHERE` clause does not match `11.0` or `101.3`.

The reason for changing the table aliases is because the query with table abbreviations is much easier to follow.